# Editing data encapsulated in flags from text file

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I am currently cleaning data from text files. And the files contains transcriptions of speeches from daily conversations. Some of the files are multilingual, a few examples of a multilingual portion are like so:

```
around that area,<tamil>அம்மா:ammaa</tamil> would have cooked too
```

```
so at least need to <mandarin>跑两趟:pao liang tang</mandarin>,then I told them that it is fine
```

*There can be multiple of such other languages in one file*

Going back to the first example, what I am trying to do with the data is to remove `"<tamil>"`, "அம்மா:" and `"</tamil>"`, keeping just the english pronunciation of the word. I have tried to replace the `<tamil>` to "", but am quite unsure of how to approach the removal of the tamil words.

The expected output would be:

```
around that area, ammaa would have cooked too
```

```
so at least need to pao liang tang,then I told them that it is fine
```

How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Pls try this

```
content="around that area,<tamil>அம்மா:ammaa</tamil> would have cooked too"

ft=' '.join([word for line in [item.strip() for item in content.replace('<',' <').replace('>','> ').split('>') if not (item.strip().startswith('<') or (item.strip().startswith('&') and item.strip().endswith(';')))] for word in line.split() if not (word.strip().startswith('<') or (word.strip().startswith('&') and word.strip().endswith(';')))])
outputs=ft.encode('ascii','ignore')

print(outputs.decode('utf-8')) 

​
```

output

```
around that area, :ammaa would have cooked too
```

It's not complete output..Like if you see final string there some extra things like ":", some punctuations..So pls edit them yourself using regex..I've posted 99% of the answer

Comment: Hi,so  sorry that I was not clear in my initial post, I did not mean to just keep the word ammaa,  I have just edited the post again, what I meant to do was to remove the tags and the tamil words, keeping the english pronunciation and the surrounding text too.

Comment: pls update expected outputs ~Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have just updated the expected outputs, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Hi, I've edited the code

Comment: I've edited again..Pls check once

Comment: Hi, I have added the code to my current code as there are other things that I have been cleaning too, I have gotten an error "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes", is it due to the last 2 lines of the code?

Comment: This is not how community works...All we just helps & guide what is the process...I've given you 99% of solution...Still asking for 1% is not fair dude

Comment: Im really sorry about that. Thank you for being so patient and helpful! I will try to figure it out myself :)